# Conversion: Propositional logic to Conjunctive normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can I ask if my answer is correct or not, I am not sure if I did it right. Feel free to correct me, I always confused in solving this kind of problem. Thank you!

```
1. A∧(A→B) →B
A∧(⇀A∨B) → B
A∧(⇀(⇀A∨B) ∨ B)
A∧((A∧⇀B) ∨ B)

2. A∧B⇔A∨B
(A∧B→A∨B) ∧ (A∨B→A∧B)
(⇀(A∧B) ∨ (A∨B)) ∧ (⇀(A∨B) ∨ (A∧B))
(⇀A∨B) ∧ (⇀B∨A)
```

Comment: Steps are correct. The result is not yet in [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

Comment: Thank you for the response, yes i am hesitant always if it is in cnf already or not. can you help me how or whats next step to do?

Comment: I'm referring to 1.

Comment: oh ok, thank you. What rule should I apply next to make it in CNF?